# I want to display A$ in React form input but return value only number;

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to display A$ in input.

```
<form [formGroup]="incomeForm" *ngFor="let field of incomeFields">      
    <mat-form-field fxFlex>
      <input matInput [value]="incomeForm.get(field).value | currency : 'AUD':'symbol':'1.0-0'"
                     [placeholder]="field"
                     [formControlName]="field">
    </mat-form-field>     
</form>
```

But this gives me Pipe error

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'A$12 is not a number' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'

This is because when I type 12, value becomes A$12 and it is trying to pipe A$12
How can I display number with A$ without error?

Comment: AUD and symbol is 'A$' ? right?

Answer (score 1):

The currency pipe only accepts numbers as valid input, so if your value is becoming 'A$12' either you can keep it and do not use currency pipe or you can slice it before sending it to the currency pipe

`{{ session.balance | slice : '2' | currency : 'AUD':'symbol':'1.0-0' }}`